# ImportError: No module named GPIO

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, modules, pi-2

I have install RPi.GPIO 5.3a from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

I ran the next code:

`sudo python setup.py install`

there are no fails on the installing.

I will run the next script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # set board mode to Broadcom

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)  # set up pin 17
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)  # set up pin 18

GPIO.output(17, 1)  # turn on pin 17
GPIO.output(18, 1)  # turn on pin 18
```

I see now the next:

```
ImportError: No module named GPIO
```

when I have done the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-rpi.gpio
```

The importerror does not go away.

I use the raspberry pi 2 with raspbian

Comment: Did you call your script RPi.py? Or do you have a dir called RPi in the crurent dir? If yes, change it's name.

Comment: I did my script call RPi.py and it's not working.

Comment: Jest rename your file. You called it RPi.py. python uses it as a module and tries to import GPIO from it.

Comment: Not finding the modules still sounds to me that the modules are not in the right path according to the python version used. I guess raspian comes with python2 and python3. Which one is used for running the script? Against which (which `pip`) is used to install the modules?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi libraries are in a state of flux because of the changes required to work on the Pi 2.

Either wait for a while for a stable version to be available from the Raspbian repositories or install a development version according to the instructions at http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/install/

Summary

```
To install the latest development version from the project source code library:

$ sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip
$ sudo apt-get remove python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
$ sudo pip install hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code#egg=RPi.GPIO
$ sudo pip-3.2 install hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code#egg=RPi.GPIO

To revert back to the default version in Raspbian:

$ sudo pip uninstall RPi.GPIO
$ sudo pip-3.2 uninstall RPi.GPIO
$ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
```

Comment: it does not work for me? what am I doing wrong? I followed all the steps ..

Answer (score 1):

I have a fresh [NOOBS 1.4.1 Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) install and I'm able to import without a problem:

```
pi@mediapi ~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>> GPIO
<module 'RPi.GPIO' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPi/GPIO.so'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, Upgrade, Re-install and do all the things necessary.

Then try the command 'import RPi.GPIO'.

(Remember - R and P are in higher case in RPi, and GPIO has all higher case letters.)

Worked for me in python 2.7.13

Answer (score -2):

Use sudo python3 filename.py, this worked for me.